# Unit testing a filter component using Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, karma-jasmine

I have created a component for filtering out a string passed to it. I am trying to write unit test for it and it throwing me an error related to constructor. Please help me.

```
import angular from 'angular';
import filter from "./format-string.filter"

angular
.module( "filters.truncateString", [] )
.filter( "truncateString", () => filter );

class TruncateString {
 filter(val){
    const accValue = val.split('YYYY');
    const firstValue= accValue[1].replace(/^(|-?\d+)$/, '');
    return `${accValue[0]} ${firstValue} AAA`;
 }
}

export default TruncateString .filter;`
```

Test I have written is

```
import angular from 'angular';
import 'angular-mocks';
import TruncateString from './format-string.filter';
describe('TruncateString filter', () => {
let controller, filter;

beforeEach(angular.mock.module('filters.TruncateString'));
controller = new TruncateString();

beforeEach(inject(function(_$filter_){
    filter = _$filter_;
}));

it('Checking whether the function is returning formatted string', () => {
    const result = controller.filter('123YYY3213123');
    expect(result).toHaveBeenCalledWith('123 YYY ... 23');
});
});
```

Comment: I believe you should not mock anything here, just include a real module that does contain the filter

Comment: @LuninRoman thanks for the response. If I don't mock the module then I am getting an error 'Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you could test a filter

```
describe('Test My Filter', () => {
  let $filter;

  beforeEach(() => {
    module('filters.TruncateString');

    inject((_$filter_) => {
      $filter = _$filter_;
    });
  });

  it('should test filter behavior', () => {
    let result = $filter('truncateString')('testval');
    expect(result).toEqual('expectedval');
  });
});
```

Comment: it worked! thank you so much. I had to just change module to angular.mock.module.